# Error Number: 42000 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Must specify table to select from. SELECT *

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, sql-server-2008

> Error Number: 42000 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]Must specify table to select from. SELECT * Filename:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\rumahku\system\database\DB_driver.php Line Number: 331

I use `codeigniter 3.xxx` and database `sql server 2008 r2` , i want to select database , but error this message like title .

my code in is

```
public function index()
    {

        $this->db->query('SELECT * from t_barang');

        $data = $this->db->get()->result_array();
            var_export($data);die();
        $data['view'] = 'barang/index.php';
        $data['title'] = 'Barang';
        $data['subtitle'] = 'Daftar data barang';
        $data['username'] = $this->session->userdata('username');


        $this->load->view('layout/admin', $data);
    }
```

please help me ,

Comment: try a query like: `use [database name here]`

Comment: `$this->db->query('SELECT <database>; SELECT * from t_barang');`

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the Query Builder properly

Try this instead

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * from t_barang');
$data = $query->result_array();
```

OR

```
$query = $this->db
    ->select("*")
    ->from("t_barang")
    ->get();
$data = $query->result_array();
```

> The Codeigniter Documentation is very clear about this.
>   Maybe the following Links could help you:
>
> [Generating Query Results](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html)
>
> [Query Builder Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html)